# "This is to inform you" vs "This is you to inform"

Tags: sentence-construction

Could you please let me know that the meaning of both sentences are same or different? 
And please let me know the 2nd sentence is correct in terms of words' Sequence  **you and to inform** as well as

**This is to inform you that** we have carefully reviewed your estimate on the parking lot refurbishing.

Or

**This is you to inform that** we have carefully reviewed your estimate on the parking lot refurbishing.

Thanks,
Charmi

Comment: The first sentence is correct. But not the second one. Inform whom? Inform you! The second sentence will be correct if we use *you* as the subject of the infinitive clause and for that you have to use a *for* before *you*, but the meaning wouldn't be the same as first sentence. The second sentence thus formed would mean *You will inform that...*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second sentence has no literal (or idiomatic) meaning at all; it simply does not parse correctly.

The first sentence means "**The purpose of this [letter or whatever] is to make sure you're informed that** we have carefully reviewed your estimate on the parking lot refurbishing."

---

If you want to get tricky, you can rearrange things a bit to say "This is *to you inform* that…", but this is archaic and confusing even to most native speakers. Don't try it unless you're writing poetry. (It's basically identical in meaning, just switching around the verb and the object. The only difference, besides being pretty hard to understand and having a different rhyme and meter, is that it emphasizes the object a little more. Think of it like "to inform *you*", except subtler.)

Comment: Nathan, "I wanted to inform you that....." is a correct sentence right or "I wanted you to inform that....."

Comment: @CharmiSapariya, the first one you posted is the right one. (Or you could modify the second to use an intransitive verb like "know": "I wanted you to know that…". In this latter case, the person is knowing for themselves; you are not knowing for them. Unmodified, though, the second form is not correct.)

Answer (score 0):

*Want* can be followed by a 'to'-infinitive clause.

Such a clause may have a subject expressed, or may not. If it has, then the subject comes before the 'to' infinitive, and means that the speaker wants that subject to do whatever the clause says.

If there is no subject expressed, then the subject of the main clause is taken as the subject the infinitive clause.

So

> I want to inform you that ...

means that I want myself to be the one who informs you of whatever.

but

> I want you to inform him that ...

means that I want you to be the one who informs (him).

> *I want you to inform that

is not grammatical, because "inform" requires an indirect object, and "you" can only be the subject.

With a verb that doesn't require an indirect object, both are grammatical, and have different meanings:

> He wants to buy it.

means he wants himself to be the one who buys it.

> He wants you to buy it.

means he wants you to be the one who buys it: 'you' is the subject of "buy".